# while loop breaks to early in a appended file bash

Tags: bash, shell, file, ubuntu, while-loop

I am writing a script in bash and have some problems when I am looping a file in a appended file
code example:

```
#! /bin/bash

printFlag=false

while test $# -gt 0; do
 case "$1" in

  -p)
   shift
   printFlag=true
  ;;

  *)
   shift
  ;;
 esac 
done

#Setting up the printFile
 for i in {1..50}
 do
  echo $i >> printFile
 done

 echo ' ' >> printFile

 for i in {150..200}
 do 
  echo $i >> printFile
 done

 echo ' ' >> printFile


#print the file

if $printFlag
then

 #problem here (wont print the whole file)
 while read line
 do
 #Modify the line here... 
 echo $line      
 done < printFile


else
 #prints the whole file 
 cat printFile
fi

rm printFile

exit 0
```

if the printFlag is false then it prints as expected,

if the printFlag is true then will the output stop at after the 50 and ' ' where the file is appended EOF.

I think it is something when appending that it's adding a EOF and the while loop breaks on in but don't know how to continue

I need the while loop to keep going after the EOF to read the rest of the file.

I have tried different read [-r, -d ...]settings and wont have any effect

I am new to bash and I hope that I have explained the problem good enough for you to understand

Comment: On my machine, both versions work.  I wonder, though, if `cat` works what is the reason *not* to use it?  Can you explain how $printFlag is set and how this is to be used?  maybe that'd clarify why `cat` is not a viable solution.

Comment: the printFlag will be true if the file needs modifications else just print it, thats the reason for the while loop and reading line by line

Comment: 1) you may be looking previous runs of bad code, add a `> printfile` at the top o your script. 2) Yes, an errant EOF (Ctrl-D) seems possible, but not clear why it is happening. Examine your `printFile` with an editor that can show Hex values to confirm that hypothesis. Good luck!

Comment: I have tried to debug the file with -xxd and hexdump and can not find anything unusual just a lot of line feed (ASCII: 0a), I suppose that there are no hidden padding or such things in bash? (cannot find much on google about it)  and added > printfile with no further success. However did i manage to find a temporary solution for this with this inside the while loop 
if  ! [ -z "${line}" ];  
then 
 #Normalcode...
else 
 echo ''
 fi

so it would skip the null determined line and echo a empty instead it works

Answer (score 0):

Bash doesn't have any concept of Boolean - there are no true/false values that can be passed to if statement via $printFlag variable

Comment: This was just a smaller snip it of code to narrow down the problem. The print flag was just to direct between the while and cat function, I have added it as a parameter.

Comment: Please adjust it accordingly, some people are trying to reproduce the problem locally. You can also decrease the range and add at the beginning #!/bin/bash -x to debug step by step your script

Comment: if `printFlag=true (or false)` it will be evaluated by the `if` statement correctly.

Comment: Just tested the both versions on Ubuntu and on Debian. All 4 cases works as expected.